# @testing-library waitfor not finding element in lazy loaded component

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library, jsdom

I'm trying to use `@testing-library/react` `waitfor` to wait for a lazy loaded component before I compare snapshots.

The App.tsx is simply this:

```
const MyComponent = lazy(() => import('my/component'));

function App() {


  return (
    <Suspense
      fallback={
        <div>
          <h1>Loading&hellip;</h1>
        </div>
      }
    >
      <MyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
```

`MyComponent` is:

```
export const MyComponent = memo(() => {
  return <div data-testid='test' />;
});
```

And the test is:

```
describe('<App />', () => {
  it('should render the App', async () => {
    const { container, findByTestId } = render(<App />);
    await waitFor(() => findByTestId('test'));
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The `waitFor` timeout because `findByTestId('test')` isn't finding the component. If I replace `<MyComponent />` with `<div data-testid='test' />` then the test works as expected.

Why doesn't  render correctly if its being lazily loaded?

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) doc:

> `React.lazy` takes a function that must call a dynamic `import()`. This must return a `Promise` which resolves to a module with a `default` export containing a React component.

This is the signature of the `React.lazy` method:

```
function lazy<T extends ComponentType<any>>(
    factory: () => Promise<{ default: T }>
): LazyExoticComponent<T>;
```

So the `factory` function should be:

```
const MyComponent = lazy(() => import('./component').then(({ MyComponent }) => ({ default: MyComponent })));
```

Besides, you don't need to use `waitFor` together with `findBy*` queries, because:

> `findBy*` methods are a combination of `getBy*` queries and `waitFor`

The complete working example:

`component.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { memo } from 'react';

export const MyComponent = memo(() => {
  return <div data-testid="test" />;
});
```

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

const MyComponent = lazy(() => import('./component').then(({ MyComponent }) => ({ default: MyComponent })));

export function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense
      fallback={
        <div>
          <h1>Loading&hellip;</h1>
        </div>
      }
    >
      <MyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';
import { App } from '.';

describe('<App />', () => {
  it('should render the App', async () => {
    const { container, findByTestId } = render(<App />);
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <div>
        <h1>
          Loading…
        </h1>
      </div>
    `);
    const mycomp = await findByTestId('test');
    expect(mycomp).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <div
        data-testid="test"
      />
    `);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71926928/index.test.tsx (11.382 s)
  <App />
    ✓ should render the App (78 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 component.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   2 passed, 2 total
Time:        12.685 s
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7"
```